# sqlite database not create in my file explore android

Tags: android, sqlite

hello friends i wnat ot create sqlite databse by query so i write below code for that

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "abc";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "user";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "pin";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "key";

public DBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    System.out.println("Call");
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT,"+ KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)   {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
      }
    }
```

When i run above code it will not create database in my file explore option of my emulator any idea how can i solve? your all suggestions are applicable

Answer (score 1):

You can find your created database, named

in

```
/data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>
```

Pull it out using File explorer and rename it to have .db3 extension to use it in SQLiteExplorer

Use File explorer of DDMS to navigate to emulator directory.

Answer (score 0):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` does not create the database file until it is actually needed.

Call `getWritableDatabase()`.

Answer (score -1):

You should try below code,which check db file is exits or not.
If not then create it.

```
String DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
String DB_NAME = "your_db_name";
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    // If database not exists copy it from the assets
    boolean mDataBaseExist = checkDataBase();
    if (!mDataBaseExist) {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try {
            // Copy the database from assests
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
        }
    }
}

// Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/DatabaseName
private boolean checkDataBase() {

    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
    Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   " + dbFile.exists());
    return dbFile.exists();
}                 


 // Copy the database from assets
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutput.flush();
    mOutput.close();
    mInput.close();
}
```